# Invalid IPA testflight

Tags: iphone, ipa

All of a sudden I am getting the following error on uploading build on testflight:

> Invalid IPA: Couldn't find executable specified in Info.plist - check the value of your CFBundleExecutable key.

I tried to upload the previous build which I already uploaded on testflight, even then I got the same error. What might be the reason?

Comment: ${PRODUCT_NAME}   But I don't think that is the problem. Three days back I uploaded the same build. I uploaded successfully. But now I am getting error.

Comment: oh, the "Executable File" key?

Comment: Yes. Also can you suggest me some other site other than testflight where I can upload IOS build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution to this error. Actually there were too many builds on testflight with same productName. I changed the productName and uploaded the same build again. It uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

- Specify Architectures: armv7;
- Set Deployment target 4.3;
- Archive app;

After these changes my package was uploaded to testflight

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to Xcode 4.6 not being able to build for armv6 any more, so removal of any references to that architecture fixed it for me.